# raix:push package meteor notifications - stacking inbox

Tags: android, meteor, push-notification

I am developing a meteor app with version meteor version 1.5. I added the raix:push package and its sending notfications as desired. But if more than one notification is sent, the new notification overlaps on the previous one. Whereas I want it to be displayed as an inbox.
I tried using this :

```
`Push.send({
      from: 'appName',
      title: 'New notification',
      text: 'test',
      badge: 12,
      gcm: {
            style: 'inbox',
            summaryText: 'There are many notifications'
      },
      query: {
            userId: user.userId,
      }
});`
```

But it doesn't work. Notifications are sent as per before only.

On checking again, I saw that nothing is being entered in the gcm field of notification collection.
[image: gcm field is empty]

Another thing I noticed is that query is stored as a string whereas gcm is an object. Does that have an affect?
Also, I would like to route to a specific page onCLick on the notification. How to add that?

Comment: so i checked and theres a field 'badge' that depicts the no.of notification on the user side. But still not clear why the above method wont work. Also, i added this piece of code : gcm: {
        title : 'New notification',
         style: 'inbox',
         summaryText: "There are 2 notifications",
       },                                  and title is inserted in the db with text as a string. But none other fields (style, summaryText) makes its way to db. Why????